# Issues with nested Map in response (Jersey)

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

I am having problems unmarshalling a nested Map in Jersey:

I have a Response object defined which looks like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class NodeResponse{

    private Map<KeyEnum,Object> fieldSetMap;

    //getters and setters

}
```

My fieldSetMap object takes an Enum as the key and an Object as a value.
I am having a problem when my Object is a Map.

The output I get when my response map has an integer and a map is :

```
<nodeResponse>
    <fieldSetMap>
        <entry>
            <key>ID</key>
            <value>12334</value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <key>nestedMap</key>
            <value>["Key1=Value1","Key2=Value2"]</value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
    </fieldSetMap>
</nodeResponse>
```

My nested map seems to be converted to a String. How can I get a map here ?

I tried a wrapped object for the Map like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class NestedMapWrapper {

    private HashMap<String, Object> nestedMap = new HashMap<>();

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="nestedElementes")
    //getter

    //setter

}
```

But still doesnt help. Any clue why ?

I see the same behavior in my json response as well.

Thanks